# Knockout text for button background

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make a knockout text for button background which is purely a solid color.

Here's button:

```css
button {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em 4em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 2em;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: 0.1em solid white;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

button:focus,
button:active {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Sign Up</button>
```

So now I have button's outline and text, when I hover over it the button's background fills up with color and I want so that text would cut out from the button's background.

How can I do this using CSS?

Comment: Sorry if I'm too lazy to give you a full answer, but I guess you could take a look at [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/)

Answer (score 1):

```
button:hover {   
   background-color: *fill the color you want*;  
   color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by cut out the text from the background? If you want to hide it, you can do this:

```
button:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: That's just makes text invisible and button's background is still there

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of `-webkit-background-clip: text;` So we clip the background to take the shape of the text, and make the text color transparent, then whatever we put as the background will be shown through the text.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10em;
  color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  background-color: purple;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<button>mg</button>
```

Comment: Damn, that is almost it but not quite or I'm stupid. The thing is, I have an animated background (body) and I want my button (its text) to be transparent, the background of the button is solid color but there must be a cut out of that text on that buttons background.

Comment: You basically wants the body background to be visible through the text, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I want, do you now how to do this?

Comment: An animated background like a GIF or an animation ?

Comment: It's animated gradient

Comment: Yeah, Nop couldn't do it, it seem that it is possible, however You can check this [Site](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/) if you want to rethink you design